# Qustion about "contact us" page

Tags: php, email

The following is the code for "Contact Us" page. Is this wrong code?
When I send messages, do not go to my E-mail !
i want The correct way to write it?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['sendmail'])) {
    $to='a@example.com';
    if (mail($to,$_POST['name'],$_POST['message'])) {
        echo 'is ok';
    } else {
        echo "Error : Not Send Mail";
    }
} else {
    echo 'not ok!!!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Please define `true` and `wrong` so that we can pick one :)

Comment: you need to check this out for help http://myphpform.com/final-form.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Customized for your example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sendmail'])) {
    $to      = 'a@outlook.com';
    $subject = $_POST['name']; // I do not know if this is your email subject
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $headers = 'From: a@outlook.com' . "\r\n" . // This will appear as to who sent the email
        'Reply-To: a@outlook.com' . "\r\n" . // This will appear as to who to send the replies
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo 'is ok';
    } else {
        echo "Error : Not Send Mail";
    }
} else {
    echo 'not ok!!!';
}
?>
```